# Is CRTP version of NonCopyable pattern correct?

Tags: c++

There is a well-known pattern of NonCopyable mix-in. There is a CRTP version of it. It can be found in many libraries and many examples. But [this](https://godbolt.org/z/n4xT87) code seems to behave strange:

```
#include <type_traits>

struct NonCopyable {
public:
    NonCopyable(const NonCopyable &) = delete;
    NonCopyable& operator=(const NonCopyable&) = delete;

protected:
    NonCopyable() = default;
    ~NonCopyable() = default;
};

template<typename T>
struct NonCopyableCRTP {
public:
    NonCopyableCRTP(const NonCopyableCRTP &) = delete;
    T& operator=(const T&) = delete;

protected:
    NonCopyableCRTP() = default;
    ~NonCopyableCRTP() = default;
};

struct Test : private NonCopyableCRTP<Test> {};

int main() {
    Test t, t2;

    static_assert(std::is_copy_assignable_v<Test>); // <--- what?
    t2 = t; // <--- this works!

    static_assert(!std::is_copy_assignable_v<NonCopyable>);
    static_assert(std::is_copy_assignable_v<NonCopyableCRTP<int>>);

    return 0;
}
```

CPPInsights shows what is going on. But I have a question - are all those CRTP examples of NonCopyable around the web broken? And how can we fix them? Should this line:

```
T& operator=(const T&) = delete;
```

be replaced with this one:

```
NonCopyableCRTP<T>& operator=(const NonCopyableCRTP<T>&) = delete;
```

Comment: If you took this from the More C++ Idioms wikibook: the [discussion page](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Talk:More_C%2B%2B_Idioms/Non-copyable_Mixin) seems to agree with you.

Comment: I took it from some video on youtube, got suspicious, googled it. Came across this wikibook and a number of other teaching examples, but this is half the problem. This implementation exists in a number of libraries. Thanks for pointing at the discussion, didn't find it myself.

Comment: This is a terrible idea, why wouldn't you simply `Test& operator=(const Test&) = delete;`, and ignore the non-sensical inheritance?

Comment: Personally I would rely on a simple noncopyable  class, without any CRTP. Like boost does. I understand why it doesn't work. But this example is what you can come across in videos and articles, where it is presented as a good way to use CRTP. So I thought either I didn't understand smth or those examples are misguiding.

Comment: You are correct it's straight up wrong, as you've proven. There are more bad advice on C++ out there than good, don't take them on faith. Also, tag people (@Vasilij) if you are directing your comment a them.